# Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']' Android Studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Android Studio and Firebase Realtime Database and I'm trying to add a value event listener to one of the nodes I created. The code looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference rdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rdb.child(Constants.JOBS_COLLECTION).child(AppData.getInstance().getJobDocRef())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                          //my code here
}
```

The Constants.java has this `public static final String JOBS_COLLECTION = "jobs";`
AppData.java is a singleton and the getJobDocRef() returns the reference of the node I created. Here is how I saved the ref:

```
AppData.getInstance().setJobDocRef(newDoc.toString());
```

When this code runs I get this exception:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: https://myproject-77d.firebaseio.com/jobs/-Ly3GYAaKy-gmVwJqajO. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validatePathString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:45)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:102)
        at com.bleek.App.FindDriverFragment.getDriver(FindDriverFragment.java:82)
        at com.bleek.App.FindDriverFragment.onCreateView(FindDriverFragment.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5719 SIG: 9
Process 5719 terminated.
```

Here is the structure of my database:

```
myproject-77d
    jobs
        -Ly3GYAaKy-gmVwJqajO
        -Ly3GHeQVxuqhXD4fFDG
```

Please help me resolve this error

Comment: you just have to provide Ly3GYAaKy-gmVwJqajO

Comment: @Ashish you mean that I should remove the hyphen "-" at the beginning of the node reference?

Comment: yes you don't need to provide - in the start of node

Comment: Thanks @Ashish but it's not working even when I remove the hyphen (exception stays the same). I believe that node reference is not the exact problem because I got it from the database when I wrote this code: DatabaseReference newDoc = rdb.child(Constants.JOBS_COLLECTION).push();

Answer (score 0):

Google helped me fix this error, in case anyone else may have this issue, I will share the solution here.

When saving the node reference I used `newDoc.toString()` this is what causes the error, I should be using `newDoc.getKey()`